# Script Output to a file

Tags: shell

Why am I unable to have the output to a file, dir_, from shell script ?

Here is the command in script:

userid]# vi script.sh

```
#! /bin/bash
echo `grep -w 7171 $ABC` > /home/username/dir/dir_$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S).csv
```

userid]# ./script.sh
./script.sh: line 13: /home/username/dir/dir_20141201_160840.csv: No such file or directory

Well I expected the script to create a new file.

Please advise the workaround.

Regards,
Ashish

Comment: Does `/home/username/dir` exist? Also that `echo` is entirely unnecessary and actively causes issues with spaces in the `grep` results.

Comment: yes, /dir does exists. So, how better should it be written ?

Comment: `grep -w 7171 "$ABC" > ...` there's literally no need for `echo` there.

Comment: And if `/home/username/dir` exists then you should check permissions on it but I would expect a different error from that scenario in most cases.

Comment: Thanks. But when I run `grep -w 7171 "$ABC" > ` WHERE $ABC is a file name, it throws an ERROR: `grep: : No such file or directory`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65978/discussion-between-erab-and-etan-reisner).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
([ ! -d /home/username/dir/ ] && mkdir /home/username/dir/) && grep -w 7171 $ABC > /home/username/dir/dir_$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S).csv
```

- `[ ! -d /home/username/dir/ ]` test if the directory exists
- `mkdir /home/username/dir/` creates the directory if it doesnt exist.
- `rep -w 7171 $ABC > /home/username/dir/dir_$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S).csv` grep the result to the file

Answer (score 0):

Probably because `dir` does not exist. You will have to create it:

```
~$ echo "a" > f
~$ echo "a" > dir/f
-bash: dir/f: No such file or directory
~$ mkdir dir
~$ echo "a" > dir/f
~$
```